# Selected/Current State for Navigation Menu

Tags: html, css, hover

I've created my navigation menu using CSS and an image sprite for the rollover states (i.e hover, active). However, I'm trying to create a 'selected/current' state (which in my case is the same as the active state) so that dependent on the page you've selected, the corresponding navigation button is highlighted.
Here's what I have:

CSS:

```
#menu li {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
height: 50px;
list-style: none;
display: inline;
float: left;
line-height: 40px;
}

#menu a {
display: block;
height: 50px;
}

#menu a:hover {
background-image:url(../Images/about_rollover.gif)
}

#about {
width: 90px;
}

#about a:hover {
background-position: 0 -50px;
}

#about a:active {
background-position: 0 -100px;
}

#about a:selected {
background-position: 0 -100px;
}

#portfolio {
width: 90px;
}

#portfolio a:hover {
background-position: 90px -50px;
}

#portfolio a:active {
background-position: 90px -100px;
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li id="about"><a href"#"></a></li>
    <li id="portfolio"><a href="portfolio.html"></a></li>
</ul>
```

Image sprite: [view here](http://i875.photobucket.com/albums/ab313/jamiepaulsmith/about_rollover.gif)

Comment: Please show us the image you're using for better understanding.

Comment: I've added a link to my sprite image

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this would be to put a class on the body tag that identifies the page you are currently browsing, and applying the selected state to the nav item when it falls under that particular class.  Like:

HTML:

```
<body class="about">
    <ul id="menu">
        <li id="about"><a href=...
```

CSS:

```
body.about ul li.about { [selected background position] }
```

Comment: Granted, I realize that this won't programmatically handle all pages, but is simply more of a general guide to one way of solving this problem.

Answer (score 1):

**First:**
You use some language at the server level to implement the site?
If so, it would be interesting to check the page that is selected and add a specific class to mark it, for example (via php):

```
<ul id="menu">
<li id="about"<?php echo $accessedPage == 'about' ? ' class="selected"' : ''; ?>><a href"#"></a></li>
<li id="portfolio"><a href="portfolio.html"></a></li>
</ul>
```

**Second:**
You can group a css selector to hover and selected:

```
#about a:hover,
#about .selected a {
    background-position: 0 -50px;
}

#portfolio a:hover,
#portfolio .selected {
    background-position: 90px -50px;
}
```

Comment: @JamieSmith I dont understand what you meant.

Comment: Well, I've tried implementing your suggestion and it hasn't worked for me?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to look at the current path some type of application logic, not strictly CSS.

For example you can use javascript:

```
$('document').ready(function () {

    //Gets the current window location
    var currentPath = window.location.pathname;


    /*Logic to identify where the user is relative
    to your webpage and update the style*/
    if (currentPath = '/portfolio')
    {
        $('portfolio').addclass('menuactive');
    }
});
```

You will have to add classes define the states for your different menu items.  But this should get you in the right direction.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a noob when it comes it web design - so what you've said doesn't make a whole lot of sense to me.

Comment: **Here is an example [link](http://jsfiddle.net/yMmuE/)**   Ultimately the answer to your question is you have to have some way to identify where the user is.  After you have that you can use a variety of methods to change the style to display your menu the way you would like.

Comment: Yes, I have Jquery set up in my project.